# Hurwitz zeta function for $s=0$ $\zeta(0,1/2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, special-functions, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I'm studying the Casimir Effect with perfect spherical boundary which involves the use of the Hurwitz zeta function. I've been staring for a while at this equation:

\begin{align}
     \sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\left(l+1/2\right)^0=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(l+1/2\right)^0}-1=\zeta(0,1/2)-1
      \end{align}

But I can't understand the first step. Where does that $-1$ come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the [Hurwitz zeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) function is given by
$$
\zeta(z,q):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(n+q\right)^z}
$$ The index starts at $0$. It explains formally why you have $-1$.

Comment: I feel so dumb... Thanks!